# Kotlin sorting array of a class based off a var inside the class

Tags: arrays, sorting, kotlin

I am having trouble finding the right code to sort my array. Inside my array is an array of a class I have created. Inside the class, there is a variable called Rank that contains an Int. I would like to sort my array based off that number inside the class (highest to lowest). I am new to the Kotlin language, but experienced with the Swift language. The Swift code equivalence to what I am trying to achieve is:

```
TrendingArray.sort(by: {$0.Rank > $1.Rank})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
array.sortBy { it.rank }
```

Here's the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html

Comment: Thank you! This works but now my problem is that it orders it from lowest to highest when I want it to go from highest to lowest. How can this be done?

Comment: I figured it out. What I was looking for was array.sortByDescending